# NSTimer from secondary NSThread doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

As per the documentation of [Run Loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW7) if there is any input source NSThread will be running otherwise it will go to sleep. I configured the timer same as provided under "Configuring Timer Sources" in above link but its not triggering. I am using below code.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(testOnThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) testThread
{

    NSLog(@"Test");
}


-(void)testOnThread
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSRunLoop* myRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

        // Create and schedule the first timer.
        NSDate* futureDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0];
        NSTimer* myTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:futureDate
                                                    interval:0.1
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(testThread)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        [myRunLoop addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
}
```

Above code never prints "Test".

But timer is firing every time if I put `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];` at the end of `-(void)testOnThread` methods it works fine([Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095991/problems-launching-an-nstimer-from-a-secondary-thread)). My query is if we are already providing timer input Source to run loop than what is the need to explicitly start it using `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];`

Comment: Doing `run` locks the thread into the run loop until the loop is drained, preventing the thread from exiting immediately and deleting the run loop, before the timer expires.

Answer (score 1):

I'll let others answer the question why you have to `run` the runloop yourself. But I'd like to suggest an alternative:

If you want to run timer on background thread, using dispatch timer is easiest, IMHO, with no runloop required at all. Just define timer property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_source_t timer;
```

And then schedule the timer to run on a custom queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app.timer", 0);
self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), 20ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
    // code to be performed periodically on background thread here
});

dispatch_resume(self.timer);
```

Comment: I am using NSThread because my mac supports OS X 10.4 and later. I can't use GCD there